# convert a list with decimal number and data type to just numbers

Tags: python, list, decimal, converters

My return result from my database looks like :

```
a = [Decimal('0.4441'), Decimal('0.3821'), Decimal('0.4414'), Decimal('0.3391')]
```

How can I convert it to :

```
a = [0.4441, 0.3821,  0.4414, 0.3391]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> a = [Decimal('0.4441'), Decimal('0.3821'), Decimal('0.4414'), Decimal('0.3391')]
>>> a = [float(n) for n in a]
>>> a
[0.4441, 0.3821, 0.4414, 0.3391]
```

I don't see why you would want to do this, you are just losing precision.

Comment: it works perfect thank you very much!! I want to accept the answer but the system told me to wait 12 minutes.

Comment: can you please explain to me what do you mean with `losing precision` thank you very much again!!

Comment: @mongotop `float`s don't work like decimals, if your database gives you decimal results, you should work with them, by converting to `float` your risk encountering floating point inaccuracies (http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Note that you can perform math with decimals just like `int`s or `float`s

Comment: The real question is what do you think you need the floats for, because you can probably do the same thing with the decimals anyway.  E.g., `print ', '.join(str(x) for x in a)`

Comment: I'm calculating 25% and 75% percentiles to calculate my high and low outlieres to clean my data, it's all math calculations

Comment: @mongotop It probably won't be much of an issue, floats will prove more convenient in your calculations but your database is providing `Decimal`s for a reason so it will be more accurate to work with them if you want.

Comment: I will have to talk to the DB Admin to get that fixed because you are right! and my calculations require something very precise!! thank you so much for the very valuable info!!!

Comment: @mongotop get what fixed!? I was saying it's more accurate with `Decimal`s!

Comment: I see!!! so the format that it's on the DB is good just the way how I read it it should be decimal as well. now I got it!!!! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the index 0, as in:
for i in a:
    print(i[0])

this will get rid of the "extra information" and will only leave you your number (in decimals).